# How to write bit in dataOutputstream in java

Tags: java

I want to write 2 bytes of data as a bit. My bit value is 00010000 00000000 these two bytes data I want arrange in bit.

Requirement:

```
1 bit - 0
1 bit - 0 
1 bit - 0 
1 bit - 1
1 bit - 0 
1 bit - 0 
1 bit - 0 
1 bit - 0 


4 bit - 0
1 bit - 0 
1 bit - 0 
2 bit - 0
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want arrange in bit"? Your question is very unclear at the moment. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: This looks like RLE compression but seems to have arbitrary counts which  you don't explain. Do you want to compress data, e.g. by using bit fields intermingled with other data? As an example: why split 8 0-bits into groups of 4, 1 and 2 instead of something else?

Comment: I want to write 2bytes of data as bit arrangements

Comment: You're repeating your question. What we want to know: what do you understand by `bit arrangements`? And how would you want to write them into the file? As individual bytes alternatingly containing the number of the bytes and the value?

Comment: Using data output stream I'm writing char..short...double...int... I want to write 2 bytes of data as bit

Comment: I'm writing into network.. Its a flag value.. Each bit have 0 and 1 .. 16bits I want to write bit

Comment: You can't write individual bits to a stream. Combine the flags into a byte value (or int and cast that to byte, just be careful to use only the least 8 bits) and write those bytes to the stream. Combination would be done using the bitwise operator `|`, e.g. `byte b = 1 | 2;` for creating the byte (in bits) `00000011`. Additionally you might want to use the shift operators `<<` and `>>`.

Comment: Thomas : can you please write it ?? My bit value is 00010000 & 00000000 so if I Byte.parseByte("00010000",2) is 16

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write a single bit to a `DataOutputStream`.  The I/O granularity for all Java classes that inherit from `OutputStream` and `InputStream` is an 8 bit byte.

There are a few reasons for this:

- Efficiency - the cost of writing data one bit at a time is prohibitive.
- The OS-level API's (syscalls) do not support this; read "man 2 read" and "man 2 write" in the UNIX / Linux manual pages.
- The places you are writing to (files, sockets, pipes and so on) are all modelled by the operating system with 8 bit bytes as the data granularity.  You can't write 1 bit to a file without supplying 7 more.
- 8 x N bit granularity applies down at the hardware level for disk controllers, network interfaces and so on.  And in the standards for network communication ... right down to ISO/OSI level 1.

---

Having said that, there is nothing stopping you from designing and implementing your own Java API that allows you to write (or read) 1 bit at a time.  The problem is that at the point you come to interact with the operating system (either via Java I/O classes, or in native code), your API's implementation has to be writing (or reading) bundles of 8 x N bits.

Has anyone one done this already?  Well apparently, the answer is "yes".  Google for "java bitstream class" or "java bitstream library".  (Sorry, but no links because I think bitstream APIs are a nutty idea, and I don't want to encourage you to waste your time with them ...)

Comment: byte b = 0;
byte c = 0;
b = (byte) (b | (1 << 4));
mout.writeByte(b);
mout.writeByte(c);

Comment: You are not writing a bit there.  You are writing two bytes ... 16 bits. 1 bit != 16 bits ... in the English language ...

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to write bits into OutputStream with [JBBP framework](https://github.com/raydac/java-binary-block-parser)
either through JBBPBitOutputStream or with JBBPOut

```
JBBPOut.BeginBin().Bit(false,false,false,true,true,true).End().toByteArray();
```